# Can I apply for a Japanese tourist/ordinary visa 7 months before my travels?

Tags: visas, japan, tourist-visas, embassies, colombian-citizens

I am a Colombian citizen. I'm planning a trip to Japan on my vacation from work, around October 9-27, 2018. I asked my travel agency about applying for the visa. I was told that Embassy would not let me apply so far in advance, to apply a minimum 2 months before my trip.

I've been reading the [Japanese Embassy](http://www.colombia.emb-japan.go.jp/ESP/consular/visas.htm) web site and I don't see anything related to that. Do they mean that it may be harder to get the visa if I apply so long in advance? Does it work like that?

My idea is to apply for it this month, February, or March.

I want to start planning the trip and buy the tickets. If I apply for the visa 2 months before, and they deny me the visa, I will lose the money and the time that went into planning the trip. I also want to apply for the visa now because the tickets will be cheaper than 1-2 months before the trip.

Edit: I have been told that I can't do that because I can't specify the date I want to get the visa. For example, if I apply for it now I will get a visa available for the next 3 months.

Comment: Your English is just fine, but I did a bit of an edit to tighten it up, if that's okay with you. If I've misunderstood, I apoligise. You can use the 'edit' button to adjust it :)

Comment: You have know your dates and hotel reserved in order to apply, so you must plan before knowing if you will be denied. I also dislike this dependency but it is common in many countries visa applications.

Comment: @Itai thats the thing I dont really know if its true,cause I dont see anything in the web related to that. and well I can get the confirmation for the flights with the travel agency if I need them for the apply

Comment: Did you read the form for the visa? It asks you the name and address of the hotel you will stay at... among other things. If you haven't, I suggest you read through it and see was you need to have before you can fill it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible because you cant select the valid period of the visa, you will only get it for the next 3 months after your request